# .json file not found when it is there

Tags: eclipse

Why is Eclipse saying that my .json file is not found? It is located off my main project at:
StockIODebug/assets/StockIODebug.json

I have tried moving the .json file to different folders but no luck. I am starting to think there is something more to this than just can't find the file.

```
    public void clickme (View view) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/assets/StockIODebug.json"));

            //Read entire file as object
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonObject);  

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    } 
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-04 21:31:00.356: I/Timeline(24149): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@faa2ff9 time:78464377
03-04 21:31:01.106: D/ViewRootImpl(24149): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-04 21:31:01.156: D/ViewRootImpl(24149): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-04 21:31:01.166: W/System.err(24149): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/StockIODebug.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at com.example.stockiodebug.MainActivity.clickme(MainActivity.java:37)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
03-04 21:31:01.186: W/System.err(24149):    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure (without logging into your computer!!), but the most likely explanation is that the file *really* isn't "there".  That is, it really is not in the directory "/assets".  Note that that is an *absolute* pathname for a directory in the root directory of your file system.

Problems like this usually turn out to be a misunderstanding of what a pathname means.  My guess is that you are trying to load an asset file in your project.  In that case, you either need to:

- prefix the path with the absolute pathname of the project
- "cd" to the project before running your app, and then use a *relative* pathname
- make sure that the folders containing your assets are in your app's classpath (e.g. in the app's JAR file) and use the classloader to load them.

If your application is intended to be packaged / distributed for others to use, that last approach is the recommended way.  (All other things being equal ....)

Comment: Hi Stephen -  The .json file is intended to be packaged as part of the app.  If I am unable to load it using the code I have, is there another means to load and read in the file?  What is also odd is that when I created a java console app, the same code works just not on Android.  Apologies for the newbie question, I am completely new.

Comment: I have added a reference on loading resources from the classpath.